# Solving a simple string expression in java (android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making a simple calculator app. I will get simple string expressions in the form of "1+2*3/4". no brackets or anything. Now i want to solve this expression when user presses = button. I found this really simple working piece of code for this purpose:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String foo = "40*4+8/2";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } 
}
```

But the problem is that eclipse don't seem to resolve these imports as i probably need EE for this purpose, and i dont know how to get to that. Kindly tell me a simple algorithm or code that'd solve the string expressions or some way to enable those imports in the eclipse.

Comment: _But the problem is that eclipse don't seem to resolve these imports_ The `javax.script` package is not part of the Android API. You will have to develop your own solver or pick an external library

Comment: Isn't there any pre defined algorithm for this sort of thing? i dont want to waste my time on developing my own logic for this.

Comment: I really don't know :/ for my android app I had to develop my own solver... Some time ago I saw that you can use a `WebView` to evaluate your javascript function and then return the results by overriding a method in the `WebView`, but I really don't know how to do it

Comment: No worries bro, i'll keep searching